# How to calculate the angle of 2 curves on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Calculate the angle of the curves $(C1) : u = v-1$, $(C2): u=3-v$ on the surface $(S):$
$$\textbf{r}(u,v) = u\cos v\ \textbf{i} + u\sin v\ \textbf{j} +u^2\ \textbf{k}$$

I know the angle of two coordinate curves is the angle of the tangent lines at the intersection point, but I'm not sure how to apply this.

Comment: I've edited your surface equation so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to find the intersection point of the two curves.

The tangent vectors at a point $\textbf{r}(u_0,v_0)$ have the nice formula of
$$
\frac{\partial\textbf{r}}{\partial u}\bigg\vert_{(u_0,v_0)}\ \ \ \text{ and  }\ \ \ \frac{\partial\textbf{r}}{\partial v}\bigg\vert_{(u_0,v_0)}\ .
$$
Think you can take it from there?

Comment: Yes, so I found r_u =  cos(v)i + sin(v)j + 2uk and r_v = -usin(v)i + ucos(v)k

Comment: Now you can find the tangent vectors for the intersection point, which you get by solving the simultaneous equations C1 and C2 to get a specific value for $u$ and $v$. Plug those values into the tangent vector equations to get the two tangent vectors, then use the dot product to get the angle between them.